# Which user:group for my website root folder to be able to run composer update?

Tags: php, composer-php, file-permissions, pimcore

I have a Pimcore project root folder which is recursively owned by `www-data:www-data`.

If I use `sudo composer update`, everything works fine, but many files will be set with root owner, which might cause further problems.

If I use `sudo -u www-data composer update`, I get a *RuntimeException*:

```
file_get_contents(/home/me/.composer/config.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

If I use `sudo -u me composer update`, at some point, I get another *RuntimeException*:

```
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                             
  Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to write in the cache directory (/var/www/html/pimcore/skeleton/var/cache/dev)
```

If I change ownership of the root folder to `me:www-data`, then I get *RuntimeException* error because some folders are not writable for the group `www-data`, like this folder `/var/www/html/pimcore/skeleton/var/cache/dev/twig` which permissions are set to `drwxr-xr-x`.

By which `user:group` should my root folder owned by and how should I run `composer update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's better if you do not run composer as root](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md).

Besides that, it's not particularly important which user do you use to run composer. As long as it has enough permissions to write on your project files (typically only on `vendor`, `bin`, `var`, and `public`; although it might need to write on different directories depending on the type of project.

Since you already run `composer` as root, it seems that `/home/me/.composer/config.json` has been created with `root` ownership, which is bringing you additional problems. Just `sudo chown` that file so it can be read by your own user.

Set the project so all the files belong to your (non-elevated privileges) user, and **after** running `install` fix the permissions as recommended in the documentation:

- [Pimcore: File Permissions](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/File_Permissions.html)
- [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/file_permissions.html)

Comment: Actually, it's not enough. I always get `The stream or file "/var/www/html/pimcore/skeleton/var/logs/dev.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied` after a while.

Comment: It is enough. If you are getting that error it means you need to fix the permissions for `var` (recursively), so that the `www-data` user can write in that folder and file.

Comment: At some point, `dev.log` is going back to `my-user:my-user` permissions, maybe I should move the cronjob `console maintenance` from `my-user` to `www-data`.

Comment: Well, yes. If after setting the right permissions you run another job that for X reasons change them back... you are back to square zero. No idea what `console maintenance` does, but running it as `www-data` seems wise.